# Avoiding or replacing multiple Where-Object statements

Tags: powershell, filtering

I have a script containing a function `Create-RebootData` containing child functions such as `Full` and `Full` has a child function named `Generate-RebootData` where the output variable `$Global:result` is created.

Within `Full` there are multiple `Where-Object` two statements to filter the `$Global:result` into by date and time.  Example below.

**Is there an easier method to accomplish this instead of the multiple `Where-Object` statements?**

The desired result are

```psh
Set-StrictMode -Version 1.0
Function Create-RebootData{

[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true,DefaultParameterSetName="ViewOnly")]
    Param(

[Parameter(ParameterSetName="ViewOnly")]
    [Switch]$ViewOnly,

[Parameter(ParameterSetName="Full")]
    [Switch]$Full,
    )

    Switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName){
"ViewOnly"
{
    ViewOnly
}
"Full"
{
    Full
}
    }#end switch

Function Full{
Generate-RebootData

  $Global:result | Where-Object {$_ -like '*fri?2:00*' -and $_.MaintenanceWindow `
  -notmatch 'all.da.servers' -and $_.Server -match "^ITD"} | % {"{0}" -f $_.Server} | `
  Out-File D:\Scripts\Full-Servers.txt -Append

  $Global:result | Where-Object {$_ -like '*fri?2:00*' -and $_.MaintenanceWindow `
  -notmatch 'all.da.servers' -and $_.Server -match "^ITD"} | `
  % {"{0}" -f $_.MaintenanceWindow -replace `
  "^NA.+", "$((get-date).AddDays(1).ToString('MM-dd-yy')) 01:50"} | `
  Out-File D:\Scripts\Full-Times.txt -Append

}

  Function Generate-RebootData{
    IF(Get-Command Get-SCOMAlert -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){}ELSE{Import-Module OperationsManager}

    "Get Pend reboot servers from prod"
New-SCOMManagementGroupConnection -ComputerName Server01

$AlertData = Get-SCOMAlert -Criteria "MyString" | Select NetbiosComputerName

New-SCOMManagementGroupConnection -ComputerName Server02

$AlertData += Get-SCOMAlert -Criteria "MyString" | Select NetbiosComputerName

    "Remove duplicates"
$AlertDataNoDupe = $AlertData | Sort NetbiosComputerName -Unique

    "Create hash table"
$table = @{}
    "Populate hash table"

$MaintenanceWindow = Import-Csv D:\Scripts\MaintenanceWindow2.csv

$MaintenanceWindow | ForEach-Object {$table[$_.Computername] = $_.'Collection Name'}

    "Create final object"

$Global:result = @{}

    "Begin Loop"
$Global:result = $AlertDataNoDupe | ForEach-Object { [PSCustomObject] @{ 

    Server=$_.NetbiosComputerName

    MaintenanceWindow= if($table.ContainsKey($_.NetbiosComputerName)){
                $table[$_.NetbiosComputerName]
                }Else { "Not Found!"}

    PingCheck=IF(Test-Connection -Count 1 $_.NetbiosComputerName -Quiet -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){"Alive"}
        ELSE{"Dead"}

    LastReboot=Try{$operatingSystem = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $_.NetbiosComputerName -ErrorAction Stop
        [Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($operatingSystem.LastBootUpTime)}
        Catch{"Access Denied!"}
    } }
}
```

Comment: The "easier" method would be to refactor `Generate-RebootData` to take parameters like `MaintenanceWindow`, `Date`, `Server`. On a side note, using global variables to exchange data between functions is a bit of a code smell. Why wouldn't `Generate-RebootData` just return the relevant dataset?

Comment: My intention was to create this script that will be scheduled/automated and allow it to be run to create scheduled reboot data for the same day (example `(Get-Date).AddDays(0)`) Generate-RebootData just collects data from SCOM and creates a variable which is used across the child functions SaturdayOnly or SundayOnly.

Comment: Still, `$result = Generate-RebootData` and then passing `$result` to your nested functions as pipeline input or parameter arguments would make your code *way* easier to read and thereby easier to maintain. As an added bonus, if someone uses the script in another context than your original one, they won't get their scope polluted with data that should've been kept local to the scope of these functions

Comment: I'm sort of understanding, instead of being lazy and calling the function `Generate-RebootData` I assign that function to a variable but my challenge becomes making `Generate-RebootData` output an object.

Comment: Post the contents of the `Generate-RebootData` and I'll try to help you refactor it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$Global:result | Where-Object {
    $_ -like '*fri?2:00*' -and
    $_.MaintenanceWindow -notmatch 'all.da.servers' -and
    $_.Server -match '^ITD'
} | ForEach-Object {
    '{0}' -f $_.Server | Out-File D:\Scripts\Full-Servers.txt -Append

    '{0}' -f $_.MaintenanceWindow -replace '^NA.+',
    '{0} 01:50' -f (Get-Date).AddDays(1).ToString('MM-dd-yy') | Out-File D:\Scripts\Full-Times.txt -Append
}
```

But I agree with Mathias' [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35385568/avoiding-or-replacing-multiple-where-object-statements#comment58475841_35385568), this function probably should be refactored.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this approach would need to be repeated for every day and time combo.  Friday at 1800 for example.

Comment: @user4317867 Yep, I've probably misunderstood your question: thought you need help combining two `Where-Object` pipelines.

Comment: I definitely appreciate the feedback and will make an attempt to refactor my function.